# Freezed screen and resolution screen won't work on Parrot Security OS

Tags: gnu-screen, resolution, parrotsec

Today I've been installing Parrot OS on my VM Virtualbox, when I've already istalled it, i opened a new terminal, and I typed `sudo apt update` and after that `sudo apt full-upgrade`.
When it finished, i rebooted. Then the I logged in, after that I got freezed screen. I've closed Parrot OS and VM, then i entered again and it worked. It seems like when i close the entire VM it works.

But another thing that happens, is that the resolution doesn´t work correctly, I typed `sudo vi /etc/default/grub` to change resolution. Then I changed where it says

> 9 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""$

to

> 9 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet spash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"$

After that i typed `reboot` (as i told you before i had to close and open again VM) but it didn´t work, i've tried from settings of VM but it didn't work. How can i change the resolution to 1920x1080?